# Why does my infinite carousel code break my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I've purchased a Theme Forest template which I'm using to create a website. One of the features that I wanted to include, specifically on the about.html page of the website is an infinite scrolling carousel to display client logos on. I found a good example of a carousel I wanted to use [here](https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-an-infinite-client-logo-carousel-to-your-website.stml) and followed the instructions.

I added the following HTML code to the body of my about.html page:

```
    <div class="container">
  <section class="customer-logos slider">
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/amazon.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/bbc.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/bbc2.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/bbcnews.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/bbcwales.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/itv.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/kewgardens.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="images/about/rada.jpg></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I downloaded the CSS file and included it in my index.html and about.html where the other CSS appears to be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sinister.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/slimmenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main-bg.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/infinite-slider.css">
```

I added the JavaScript code to a file called carousel.js and ensured I referenced the js file on my about.html page:

```
<script src="javascripts/libs/common.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/main.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/elements.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/carousel.js"></script>
```

I then added the following includes to the web page my carousel is on (about.html):

```
<script src="javascripts/libs/common.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/main.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/elements.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And now I've ended up with my about page not loading at all as you can see [here](http://swgameservers.co.uk/about.html). When I first tried this on my local machine, without uploading the files via FTP, the web page (about.html) worked, but the logos were displayed horizontally and didn't scroll.

I can usually get by with the basics but I'm clearly missing something, or perhaps the code I'm trying to implement is somehow conflicting with the template?

Comment: Have you checked your console?  I see this error: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
`  This indicates that jQuery is not yet loaded when something on the page tries to use it.

Comment: You are including javascript files that use jQuery before loading jQuery. Please include jQuery before other js files and then let us know so we can check where is the problem with scrolling

Comment: It's probably just the order of the script includes.  If in doubt put jQuery at the top of them, as it's most likely required for most of the other scripts.

Comment: Thank you so far. I have now removed the last 4 lines of the .js section from my original post (the last lot of code I shared). Now you can see the page works and the images are not scrolling.

Comment: [Open the browser's JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), go through the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is cause you are getting an `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function` in your common.js file. javaScript compiler stop executing when it struck with an error (that is the reason why your loader is keep onloading) you can see the same by pressing f12 -> console. Here is some more info on how to resolve this issue.

go to `javaScript/libs/common.js` and search for `jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def]` and resolve the error.

Comment: Thank you. I have now got the page loading but unfortunately the carousel does not scroll.

Comment: @GeorgiePeru turns out you are getting yet another error in `/javascript/custom/carasoul.js` and the error is at  `$('.customer-logos').slick({ ` check in console `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function`